# Run app as super user?

Tags: android, networking, root

I wanted to test Unified Remote (WiFi Remote for your PC) and I wasn't able
to connect to my PC in any way (although I could ping from PC to my Android). In the instructions it said I should try a ping from my Android to the PC, so I used the Android Terminal Emulator to try a ping and it just printed this:

```
ping: icmp open socket: Operation not permitted
```

My Android is rooted so I typed `su` and tried again and it worked. So I figured that Unified Remote needs su-rights to open a socket and connect to the server on my PC! The only problem is, that Unified Remote doesn't ask for su-rights... (Like the terminal. It didn't want root rights until i used `su` and I guess the same thing happens internally with Unified Remote)

Can I somehow start an App (in this case Unified Remote) with su-rights WITHOUT having it asking???

EDIT:

So now I tried 2 other remote control apps and none of them were able to find a server (neither detect it automaticly nor manually... And yes, I have installed and opened the server!) Again -> Ping works fine.... What surprises me is that only remote control apps have that problem... For example FTP with ES File Explorer works fine... Also I have an online game wich works fine too... I don't get it :(

Answer (score 1):

Android device

```
ping: icmp open socket: Operation not permitted
```

Solution:

After Root my android mobile -  PING socket error occured and I solved the issue by setting "ping" file permission as given below:

```
           Read Write Execute
Owner       Y  -  Y  -   Y
Group       Y  -  N  -   Y
Others      Y  -  N  -   Y
------------------
Set UID:    Y   
Set GID:    
Sticky: 
------------------      
Octal Value:  4755  rwsr-xr-x
-------------------------------
```

You can edit permission by Root Explorer android software - Found - Play Store.

Answer (score 0):

If the application it self not asking you for su rights than  there is **NO** need to do it manualy.
I checked [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.Relmtech.Remote) and in description of Unified Remote I dind't find any hint that it requires su rights.

Comment: Yep... See, usually `ping` shouldn't need su-rights either. On my friends phone I can run a ping without root. (Also if you try a Ping App from the market, they also don't need root but on my device there is always this Operation not permitted message!) What I think is that Unified Remote also internally fails to open a socket because of this... I think this is only with my device... (Btw. it's an Alcatel 997d)

Comment: You can try to change "ping" binary permissions, use root explorer and navigate to "/system/bin" directory, find "ping" binary and set the permissions to 777, also try to link it to other group.

Comment: I did that. Didn't help. I still get the icmp open socket error... I read it could have something to do with raw sockets (only su can open raw sockets) I'm kinda lost right now...