# Android: ping: icmp open socket: Operation not permitted

Tags: android, root, ping

Is it possible to execute ping on Android 4.3 without root access?

Some people suggest to

[sudo chmod u+s /system/bin/ping](http://ben.goodacre.name/tech/Ping:_icmp_open_socket:_Operation_not_permitted_%28Linux%29)

or

[set the permissions to 777](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18882457/android-run-app-as-super-user)

Is this possible on Android without root?

Comment: Yes it is possible follow my answer and dont forget to vote up :)